# Name of a property in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

A multigraph is a graph which allows for *more than one edge* between a pair of nodes in a graph. What would be the name of a graph which allows for *more than one type of node*. For example, buyers and sellers. I've heard multimodal, but I don't know if that is correct.

Comment: For two types of nodes, bipartite may also fit.

Comment: Vertex-labeled graph.

Comment: A graph can also be n-partite for n>2, but bipartite graphs are far far more common.

Comment: For bipartite (and n-partite) graphs though, they generally are such that there are no edges exist between vertices within their own part in the partition.  While that may make sense in some scenarios, it certainly won't work in others.  Say for example a graph showing friendships and having one class of vertices be boys and another class be girls.

Comment: Just for clarification, if edges existed between vertices within partitions, would it be wrong to call it n-partite or would it just be considered uncommon?

Comment: In Network Science, we would say multi-layer network. If the edges only join certain types of nodes, then bipartite may fit.

Comment: @RJC It would be wrong. An $n$-partite graph specifically is one that has a partition of the vertex set into $n$ parts with no edges within a part. (Equivalently, this is an $n$-colorable graph.)

Comment: You can just have a pair $(G, L)$ where $G$ is the graph and $L$ is whatever kind of labeling of the vertex set you like. Without any further restrictions on the structure of the graph, there's not much more to say here graph-theoretically.  You don't need to define a new kind of graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are describing is referred to in network science as a heterogeneous graph. A heterogeneous graph is a graph $G = (V, E)$ such that the vertex set $V$ is a disjoint union $V = V_1 \cup V_2 \cup \dots V_n$ where each $V_i$ denotes some set of vertices that share a common label. If $G$ is a directed graph then $E$ is the disjoint union of $n^2$ edge sets, where where each edge set is denoted by $E_{(i, j)}$ and consists of edges from vertices in $V_i$ to vertices in $V_j$. When $G$ is undirected we have $E_{(i, j)} = E_{(j, i)}$ and there are only $\binom{n}{2}$ edge sets.